# BottomNavigationView disappears after Fragment Transaction

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a BottomNavigationView with 4 items inside.
In one of the Fragments (HomeFragment) i've added card view with onClickListener.

After clicking the CardView, it moves the user to a new Fragment.
When the Fragment inflates, the BottomNavigationView disappears completely, and the app crashes when Clicking the back button (on a null reference to the BottomNavigationView).

The error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.getMenu()' on a null object reference
```

The XML for the BottomNavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

The Transaction from HomeFragment:

```
            Fragment fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_home, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack("HomeFragment")
                    .commit();
```

Attached the screenshot of the HomeFragment with the BottomNavigationView appearing, and the new NotificationFragment - without the BottomNavigationView.

**HomeFragment (With Bottom Navigation)**

[image]

**NotificationFragment (Missing Bottom Navigation)**
[image]

**Expected result:**

- BottomNavigationView should appear.

**EDIT #1**

main_activity.xml - holds the fragment of BottomNavigationView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**HomeFragment.java** - Initiate the Fragment Transaction

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        CardView card = getView().findViewById(R.id.card1);
        Log.e(TAG, "Found Card!");

        card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_notifications);

                Log.e(TAG, "Starting Login Activity");
                Fragment fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_in)
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_home, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack("HomeFragment")
                        .commit();
            }
        });


    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Solved using the following:

```
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(current).navigate(R.id.navigation_notifications);
```

where current:

```
    Fragment current = this;
```

out side of the OnClickListener (current Fragment).

Comment: Can you provide your `Fragment` code? Specifically where you create and hold on to the `BottomNavigationView` instance and where you initiate the fragment transaction.

Comment: Okay I think one of the issues is that you're using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. To interact with the fragment container of `HomeFragment`'s `Activity` you need to use the latter, and pass in the container id as such `.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, fragment)`

Comment: Another issue I see is that you're using Navigation Component (i.e. `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"`) but still trying to manage fragment transactions yourself. May I ask what's the reason not to put everything in the nav graph and just call `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_to_notifications)`

Comment: I suggest reading through this if you haven't already: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Can't say anything about the crash because you haven't provided some code to show where do you create & keep the instance and where do you call `getMenu` on it

Comment: Fixed the issue using parts of your answers, i'll edit that and suggest you to post a question for upvote

Comment: Glad it helped. I summed it all up in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you used `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. To interact with the fragment container of your `HomeFragment`'s parent `Activity` you need to use the latter, and pass in the container id as such `.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, fragment)`

The second problem is that you are trying to manually manage your `Fragment` transactions while at the same time you are using Navigation Component on your `<fragment>` tag as such: `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"`

I suggest using only one of the two, in this case the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started). You can change between fragments by simply doing:

```
card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Starting Login Activity");
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_to_notifications)
        }
    });
```

where in your `mobile_navigation.xml` you'd have:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/destination_home"
    android:name="...HomeFragment"
    ...>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_home_to_notifications"
        app:destination="@id/destination_notifications"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/fade_out" />

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/destination_notifications"
    android:name="...NotificationFragment"
    .../>
```